# XML unit testing - open XML - check if it's valid - check some tags if they exists in the XML

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, parsing, vtd-xml

I have an XML that I parse with ximpleware (vtd-xml) - something like this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <S2SCTScf:SCTScfBlkCredTrf xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:S2SCTScf="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTScf:xsd:$SCTScfBlkCredTrf file:///T:/CommonData%201/CBS/CBS%20Payments%20Team/Testing/XSD/SCT/SCTScfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
    ................................        
                <CdtTrfTxInf>
                    <PmtId>
                        <EndToEndId>171766 12856615</EndToEndId>
                        <TxId>6022064LAS99</TxId>
                    </PmtId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SSSS</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                    </PmtTpInf>
.........................
```

and I want to write a junit or something - I found some Matchers for Hamcrest or something but I don't know how to open my XML and let's say how to see if it has an `XmlMatchers.hasXPath("/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/EndToEndId"))` and so on...

I also would like to test if it's a valid XML.
Can anybody give me a code to open my XML, test if it's valid and if it has some tags that I need in my java parsing code?

Thanks!

Comment: you may find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771/the-best-way-to-validate-xml-in-a-unit-test?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for the "minus" but I've been there and I didn't found the way it opens the XML or how to ckeck if I have a tag in my XML.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ this will definitely hellp you to read your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the file in vtd-xml you can do and check for the existence of a tag, you can do:

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
public class openAndTest{
   public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException{
        // open the XML file
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false) ) // namespace disabled here
           return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav(); 
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn); //bind to vn object
        ap.selectXPath("/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/EndToEndId"); // dont put xpath compilation in loop
        System.out.println(" test result is "+ap.evalXPathToBoolean());
        ap.selectXPath("/CdtTrfTxInf/PmtId/EndToEndId"); // reuse AP, but you can instantiate a separate AutoPilot object.
        System.out.println(" test result is "+ap.evalXPathToBoolean());

   }
}
```